# How to write a PostgreSQL stored function to alter jsonb array?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

I am trying to write a simple stored function in PostgreSQL .

1. This function will receive two parameters . (details jsonb & provider_details jsonb[] ) .
2. details jsonb example :- `{"category": "wood"}` and provider_details jsonb[] example is

```
{
    "category_type": "Wood",
    "category_type_id": 2
  },
  {
    "category_type": "Iron",
    "category_type_id": 3
  }
```

3 . What I want :- ( explanation is complicated (ignore it) but result looks easy to understand).

**Explanation :**

I need to check "category" of "detail" parameter(wood) exists or not in "provider_details" array of objects as "category_type"(wood ,iron ). If the category exists (or not) return two  arrays . Array 1 containing all objects with same "category" of "details" and second array , with all objects of "provider_details" not matching "details" "category".

**RESULT** :-
(I am expecting )

If function name is "get_matched_array" ,

```
SELECT get_matched_array(`{"category": "wood"}`:jsonb,{"category_type": "Wood","category_type_id": 2},{"category_type": "Iron","category_type_id": 3 }:: jsonb[])
```

**should return 2 arrays** :

```
array 1 : matched array(with 'wood'). = [{"category_type":"Wood","category_type_id": 2}]

array 2 : unmatched array ( without 'wood' , that means [{"category_type": "Iron","category_type_id": 3 } ]only ).
```

I am beginner to PostgreSQL. I know the basics. I tried to create function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_matched_array(
    details jsonb,
    provider_details jsonb[]
) RETURNS TABLE (matched jsonb[], unmatched jsonb[]) AS $$

    -- Declare the matched and unmatched variables with the jsonb[] data type
    DECLARE matched jsonb[];
    DECLARE unmatched jsonb[];

// I NEED THE LOGIC HERE ...

    -- Return the matched and unmatched arrays
    RETURN QUERY SELECT matched, unmatched;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I hope this is simple for most good PostgreSQL programmers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this function with `sql` instead of `plpgsql`, it will be a bit faster :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_matched_array(
    details jsonb,
    provider_details jsonb[]
) RETURNS TABLE (matched jsonb[], unmatched jsonb[]) LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS $$
  SELECT array_agg(y.content) FILTER (WHERE y.content->'category_type' = details->'category')
       , array_agg(y.content) FILTER (WHERE y.content->'category_type' <> details->'category')
    FROM unnest(provider_details) AS y(content)
$$ ;
```

This query first expand the `provider_details` array into a set of rows thanks to the `unnest` function.
Then we use the aggregate function `array_agg` in order to build the expecting results while filtering the rows according to your criteria on the json objects. See the manual for more details about the [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html), [their syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES), [their list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) and the [json/jsonb functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

see the result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tuR3f8E8)

Comment: I made a mistake , second argument is array [ ] , how can I call /select this function ?. I tried to call the function like "SELECT get_matched_array('{"category": "wood"}','[{"category_type": "Wood","category_type_id": 2},{"category_type": "Iron","category_type_id": 3 }]') " . But I am finding "malformed array literal" error ? What changes should I make to this function ? @Edouard

Comment: the right syntax is in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tuR3f8E8). Your syntax corresponds to a json array of type `json`, which is different from an array of json of type `json[]`

Comment: This is very accurate answer . Where can I learn more about PSQL stored functions ? Resources are very limited when I googled ? I want to learn loops, cases , logical operations , conditions ,and other important things. I am referring your above links too . @Edouard

Comment: This is correct answer . Precise @Edouard

Comment: everything is explained in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html) which is like the postgres bible. You will need some time to read, understand, and remember everything ... Take your time.